# Unable Administrator Account to Change the Ownership of a Specific File in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, user-accounts, administrator

I have an original administrator account `Alyssa` and newly created administrator account `Sub Administrator`. I want the second account to have permissions on everything except editing the `hosts` file.

So what I did is :

```
1. Right click on the `hosts` file.
2. Click `Properties`.
3. Select `Security` tab.
4. Click `Advanced` button.
5. Change Ownership to `Alyssa`.
6. In the `Permissions` tab, add `Deny` `Permission Entry` to `Sub Administrator`.
7. Then, Click `Ok`.
```

[Screenshot of the Security Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N3Ym.png)

Switching into the `Sub Administrator` account, I can still change the owner of the file to `Sub Administrator` and still edit the `hosts` file. What shall I do restrict the 2nd account from taking the ownership of the file and editing the `hosts` file?

The reason I want to do it is I don't want to be tempted to visit the sites restricted in the hosts file for productivity reasons. I want my husband to change the password of the first administrator account to something I dont know. In consequence, I can control my procrastination and focus more on my job.

We do not have access to the router settings, that's why I have to think of other ways to restrict myself from browsing time consuming sites.

Comment: That's normal. Anything done by an Admin can also be undone by an Admin.

Comment: @DavidPostill --> can I not disallow specifc admin to unable to take ownership of the hosts file only?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: @DavidPostill --> Is there any other way I can get around with this? I considered creating an admin account to install/run programs and everything else except editing the hosts file. Can I create a standard user account and allow it to run/install programs but disallow it to edit hosts file?

Comment: This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). If you tell us ([edit] the question) **why** you want this restriction we may be able to suggest a proper alternative.

Comment: @DavidPostill -> Please see my updated post.

Comment: Ask your husband to block those sites on your router and then change the router password.

Comment: @DavidPostill  We do not have access to the router settings, that's why I have to think of other ways to restrict myself from browsing time consuming sites.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `user` account and add all privileges that it needs. Admin accounts have access to everything by default.

Comment: Can you point me to a guide on how to do it?

Comment: @alyssaeliyah - Use an Administrator account you give the user account the permissions to the files.

Comment: Just google for `create new local user in windows 10`. There are a plethora of resources.